# how to display decimal places in graphing calculator while zooming ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am working on a calculator for iPad. When the user types a function, for example x^2 and then pressing a button it should open a screen with a graph of that function. While the user zooms, the coordinates should change accordingly. At the moment it works , but in maximum zoom scale it displays only integer values 1,2,3... The requirement is that while continuing zooming, it should display decimal places like 0.1 , 0.2 ... with minimum one decimal place. In the UIView drawRect method the method

```
[AxesDrawer drawAxesInRect:self.bounds originAtPoint:midpoint scale:self.scale*self.contentScaleFactor];
```

is called which which after drawing the axis it calls the

```
[self drawHashMarksInRect:bounds originAtPoint:axisOrigin scale:pointsPerUnit];
```

method to draw the labels :

```
#define ANCHOR_CENTER 0
#define ANCHOR_TOP 1
#define ANCHOR_LEFT 2
#define ANCHOR_BOTTOM 3
#define ANCHOR_RIGHT 4
#define HASH_MARK_FONT_SIZE 20.0
#define HORIZONTAL_TEXT_MARGIN 6
#define VERTICAL_TEXT_MARGIN 3
#define HASH_MARK_SIZE 3
#define MIN_PIXELS_PER_HASHMARK 25
+ (void)drawHashMarksInRect:(CGRect)bounds originAtPoint:(CGPoint)axisOrigin scale:  
(CGFloat)pointsPerUnit
{
if (!pointsPerUnit) return;
if (((axisOrigin.x < bounds.origin.x) || (axisOrigin.x > bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width)) &&
((axisOrigin.y < bounds.origin.y) || (axisOrigin.y > bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height))) {
return;
}
int unitsPerHashmark = MIN_PIXELS_PER_HASHMARK * 2 / pointsPerUnit;
//NSLog(@"unitsperhashmark %d",unitsPerHashmark);
if (!unitsPerHashmark)
{
unitsPerHashmark = 1;
}
CGFloat pixelsPerHashmark = pointsPerUnit * unitsPerHashmark;
BOOL boundsContainsOrigin = CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, axisOrigin);
if (boundsContainsOrigin)
{
if ((axisOrigin.x - pixelsPerHashmark < bounds.origin.x) &&
(axisOrigin.x + pixelsPerHashmark > bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width) &&
(axisOrigin.y - pixelsPerHashmark < bounds.origin.y) &&
(axisOrigin.y + pixelsPerHashmark > bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height)) {
return;
}
}
else
{
if ((axisOrigin.y >= bounds.origin.y) &&
(axisOrigin.y <= bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height) &&
(bounds.size.width <= pixelsPerHashmark)) {
return;
}
if ((axisOrigin.x >= bounds.origin.x) &&
(axisOrigin.x <= bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width) &&
(bounds.size.height <= pixelsPerHashmark)) {
return;
}
}   
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
int started = NO;
int stillGoing = YES;
NSLog(@"unitsperhashmark 2 %d",unitsPerHashmark);
for (int offset = unitsPerHashmark; !started || stillGoing; offset += unitsPerHashmark)
{
NSString *positiveLabel = nil;
NSString *negativeLabel = nil;
BOOL drew = NO;
CGFloat scaledOffset = floor(offset * pointsPerUnit);
CGPoint hashMarkPoint;
hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x+scaledOffset;
hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y;   
if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y-HASH_MARK_SIZE);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y+HASH_MARK_SIZE);
if (!positiveLabel) positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", offset];
//NSLog(@"positivelabel %@",positiveLabel);
[self drawString:positiveLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_TOP];
drew = YES;
}
hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x-scaledOffset;
if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y-HASH_MARK_SIZE);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y+HASH_MARK_SIZE);
if (boundsContainsOrigin) negativeLabel = positiveLabel;
if (!negativeLabel) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (boundsContainsOrigin ? 
offset : -offset)];
[self drawString:negativeLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_TOP];
drew = YES;
}
hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x;
hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y-scaledOffset;
if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x-HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x+HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
if (!positiveLabel) {
if (boundsContainsOrigin) positiveLabel = negativeLabel;
if (!positiveLabel) positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", offset];
}
[self drawString:positiveLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_LEFT];
drew = YES;
}
hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y+scaledOffset;
if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x-HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x+HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
if (!negativeLabel) {
if (boundsContainsOrigin) negativeLabel = positiveLabel;
if (!negativeLabel) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (boundsContainsOrigin ?  
offset : -offset)];
}
[self drawString:negativeLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_LEFT];
drew = YES;
}
positiveLabel = nil;
negativeLabel = nil;     
if (drew) started = YES;
stillGoing = drew;
}   
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: Here I assume,The method 
[self drawHashMarksInRect:bounds originAtPoint:axisOrigin scale:pointsPerUnit]; 
is only responsible for rendering the hashMark but not settings its value(Floating or Decimal).Debug the place where you are trying to set value for hashMark

Comment: thank you , yes this method is only responsible for drawing the labels-hashmark. Could you give me some ideas on it , please? I do not know who to handle-change the method so that it displays decimal places while zooming dynamically , i would really appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.I assume
positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", offset];
positiveLabel is responsible for drawing the string so which is formatted with %d(Decimal) 
Change it to %f(Floating) so displayed values will be in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the method so that the offset variable which is used as a step to calculate the hashmarks changes depending on the zoom. When the less hash mark is 1 , if the user continues zooming the hashmarks have a step 0.2 and if he continues zooming then they have a step 0.1. For that i used two different loops one for int hashmarks and one for float ones.
    + (void)drawHashMarksInRect:(CGRect)bounds originAtPoint:(CGPoint)axisOrigin scale:
    (CGFloat)pointsPerUnit
    {
    if (!pointsPerUnit) return;
    if (((axisOrigin.x < bounds.origin.x) || (axisOrigin.x > bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width)) &&
    ((axisOrigin.y < bounds.origin.y) || (axisOrigin.y > bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height))) {
    return;
    }
    int unitsPerHashmark = MIN_PIXELS_PER_HASHMARK * 2 / pointsPerUnit;
    if (!unitsPerHashmark)
    {
    unitsPerHashmark = 1;
    }
    CGFloat pixelsPerHashmark = pointsPerUnit * unitsPerHashmark;
    BOOL boundsContainsOrigin = CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, axisOrigin);
    if (boundsContainsOrigin)
    {
    if ((axisOrigin.x - pixelsPerHashmark < bounds.origin.x) &&
    (axisOrigin.x + pixelsPerHashmark > bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width) &&
    (axisOrigin.y - pixelsPerHashmark < bounds.origin.y) &&
    (axisOrigin.y + pixelsPerHashmark > bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height)) {
    return;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    if ((axisOrigin.y >= bounds.origin.y) &&
    (axisOrigin.y <= bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height) &&
    (bounds.size.width <= pixelsPerHashmark)) {
    return;
    }
    if ((axisOrigin.x >= bounds.origin.x) &&
    (axisOrigin.x <= bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width) &&
    (bounds.size.height <= pixelsPerHashmark)) {
    return;
    }
    }
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    int started = NO;
    int stillGoing = YES;
    float decimalUnits;
    if ((unitsPerHashmark==1) && (pointsPerUnit>86))
    {
    if (pointsPerUnit>490) {
    decimalUnits=0.1;
    }else if (pointsPerUnit>420) {
    decimalUnits=0.2;
    }else
    {
    decimalUnits=0.5;
    }
    for (float offsetFloat = decimalUnits; !started || stillGoing; offsetFloat += decimalUnits)
    {
    NSString *positiveLabel = nil;
    NSString *negativeLabel = nil;
    BOOL drew = NO;
    CGFloat scaledOffset = floor(offsetFloat * pointsPerUnit);
    CGPoint hashMarkPoint;
    hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x+scaledOffset;
    hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y-HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y+HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    if (!positiveLabel)
    {
    positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f", offsetFloat];
    if ([[positiveLabel substringFromIndex:1] compare:@".0"]==NSOrderedSame) {
    positiveLabel=[positiveLabel substringToIndex:1];
    }
    }
    [self drawString:positiveLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_TOP];
    drew = YES;
    }
    hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x-scaledOffset;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y-HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y+HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    if (boundsContainsOrigin) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",positiveLabel] ;
    if (!negativeLabel) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f", (boundsContainsOrigin 
    ? offsetFloat : -offsetFloat)];
    if ([[negativeLabel substringFromIndex:1] compare:@".0"]==NSOrderedSame) {
    negativeLabel=[negativeLabel substringToIndex:1];
    }
    [self drawString:negativeLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_TOP];
    drew = YES;
    }
    hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x;
    hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y-scaledOffset;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x-HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x+HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    if (!positiveLabel) {
    if (boundsContainsOrigin)
    {
    if ([negativeLabel characterAtIndex:0]=='-') {
    positiveLabel=[negativeLabel substringFromIndex:1 ];
    }else
    {
    positiveLabel = negativeLabel;
    }
    }
    if (!positiveLabel) positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f", offsetFloat];
    if ([[positiveLabel substringFromIndex:1] compare:@".0"]==NSOrderedSame) {
    positiveLabel=[positiveLabel substringToIndex:1];
    }
    }
    [self drawString:positiveLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_LEFT];
    drew = YES;
    }
    hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y+scaledOffset;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x-HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x+HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    if (!negativeLabel) {
    if (boundsContainsOrigin) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",positiveLabel] ;
    if (!negativeLabel) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f", (boundsContainsOrigin
    ? offsetFloat : -offsetFloat)];
    if ([[negativeLabel substringFromIndex:1] compare:@".0"]==NSOrderedSame) {
    negativeLabel=[negativeLabel substringToIndex:1];
    }
    }
    [self drawString:negativeLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_LEFT];
    drew = YES;
    }
    positiveLabel = nil;
    negativeLabel = nil;
    if (drew) started = YES;
    stillGoing = drew;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    for (int offset = unitsPerHashmark; !started || stillGoing; offset += unitsPerHashmark)
    {
    NSString *positiveLabel = nil;
    NSString *negativeLabel = nil;
    BOOL drew = NO;
    CGFloat scaledOffset = floor(offset * pointsPerUnit);
    CGPoint hashMarkPoint;
    hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x+scaledOffset;
    hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y-HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y+HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    if (!positiveLabel) positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", offset];
    [self drawString:positiveLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_TOP];
    drew = YES;
    }
    hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x-scaledOffset;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y-HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x, hashMarkPoint.y+HASH_MARK_SIZE);
    if (boundsContainsOrigin) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",positiveLabel] ;
    if (!negativeLabel) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (boundsContainsOrigin ? 
    offset : -offset)];
    [self drawString:negativeLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_TOP];
    drew = YES;
    }
    hashMarkPoint.x = axisOrigin.x;
    hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y-scaledOffset;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x-HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x+HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    if (!positiveLabel) {
    if (boundsContainsOrigin)
    {
    if ([negativeLabel characterAtIndex:0]=='-') {
    positiveLabel=[negativeLabel substringFromIndex:1 ];
    }else
    {
    positiveLabel = negativeLabel;
    }
    }
    if (!positiveLabel) positiveLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", offset];
    }
    [self drawString:positiveLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_LEFT];
    drew = YES;
    }
    hashMarkPoint.y = axisOrigin.y+scaledOffset;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, hashMarkPoint)) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x-HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, hashMarkPoint.x+HASH_MARK_SIZE, hashMarkPoint.y);
    if (!negativeLabel) {
    if (boundsContainsOrigin) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",positiveLabel] ;
    if (!negativeLabel) negativeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%d", (boundsContainsOrigin ? 
    offset : -offset)];
    }
    [self drawString:negativeLabel atPoint:hashMarkPoint withAnchor:ANCHOR_LEFT];
    drew = YES;
    }
    positiveLabel = nil;
    negativeLabel = nil;
    if (drew) started = YES;
    stillGoing = drew;
    }
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }